# Extract last part of the string when separator is not always the same using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have file with lines that look like this. FILE [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss4ake2b4uklub1/originalfile?dl=0)

```
ID=4;Dbxref=766;Name=LOC2;gene_biotype=protein_coding
ID=5;Dbxref=800;Name=LOC3;gene_biotype=lncRNA
ID=6;Dbxref=900;Name=LOC4;gene_biotype=protein_coding;partial=true;start_range=.,338076
ID=7;Dbxref=905;Name=LOC5;gene_biotype=pseudogene;pseudo=true
```

I'm trying to grab the last part of the string ... but the ending isn't always consistent

I've tried:

```
while read -r line ; do
        ID=`echo $line | awk -F"ID=" '{print $2}' | awk -F";" '{print $1}'`
        Biotype=`echo $line | awk -F"gene_biotype=" '{print $2}'`
        echo -e $ID"\t"$Biotype >> file.txt

done << (grep $'\tgene\t' originalfile.txt)
```

Biotype is the part that isn't working. Ideally the output would look like

```
4 protein_coding
5 lncRNA
6 protein_coding;partial=true;start_range=.,338076
7 pseudogene;pseudo=true
```

I've also tried:

```
    Biotype=`echo $line | awk -F"gene_biotype=" '{print $NF}'`
```

But it ends up saving nothing. Any advice appreciated ...

Comment: are those sample input you've shown are actually saved in a variable `line` or do you have a loop elsewhere and `line` gets one line at time? if you indeed have multiple lines, you need to use `echo "$line"` (note the double quotes)

Comment: yess, I've added more info about how the loop works ...

Comment: Apparently all you want to do is to get `ID \t Biotype` in a new file (am I right?). If so, the solution is much simpler and this is a good example of an XY problem.

Comment: How does your `while` loop get its data? I miss that: `done <file`

Comment: I;ve added more info, the script works fine ... the only part that doesn't work is Biotype, which means that I'm extracting that part of the line incorrectly ...

Comment: if you post a sample input and expected output, perhaps everything could be done in a single awk command instead of shell loop, grep, etc.. and the grep command is checking for tabs around `gene` but your sample shown doesn't have tabs..

Comment: does `sed -n '/gene/{s/ID=//; s/;.*gene_biotype=/\t/p}' originalfile.txt` solve your issue?

Comment: it's a GFF3 file ... it's a very big file, l've added a link to a sample file in the text

Comment: Any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you are using the wrong approach and should be using one of the standard UNIX text processing tools of grep, sed, or awk or a non-standard text processing tool (perl, python, ruby, etc.) instead. If you think you need some combination of grep, sed, and/or awk then you should just use awk alone. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a sed that understands `-E` to use EREs (e.g. GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/[^=]*=([^;]*)(;[^;]*){2}[^=]*=/\1\t/' file
4       protein_coding
5       lncRNA
6       protein_coding;partial=true;start_range=.,338076
7       pseudogene;pseudo=true
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/[^=]*=\([^;]*\)\(;[^;]*\)\{2\}[^=]*=/\1\t/' file
4       protein_coding
5       lncRNA
6       protein_coding;partial=true;start_range=.,338076
7       pseudogene;pseudo=true
```

---

Also, here's an approach to generally working with the type of tag=value data you have in future and that is to first create an array (`f[]` below) that maps each tag/name to it's associated value and then you can just access the values by their names for comparisons, printing, etc.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS="\t" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
    << do something with "f[tag]"s >>
}
```

which you could solve your current problem with as:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS="\t" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
    sub(/.*;gene_biotype=/,"")
    print f["ID"], $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
4       protein_coding
5       lncRNA
6       protein_coding;partial=true;start_range=.,338076
7       pseudogene;pseudo=true
```

but you can also do far more with including printing lines based on compound conditions of different values, printing columns in different order than they were input, etc. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS="\t" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = val = $i
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
}
( (f["Dbxref"] > 800) && (f["partial"] == "true") ) || (f["gene_biotype"] == "protein_coding") {
        print f["Name"], f["ID"]
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
LOC2    4
LOC4    6
```